# jQuery Mobile Slider / Carousel

Tags: jquery-mobile, jcarousel, carousel, swipe

I need to make a jQuery "Carousel" pretty similar to the one in this page: http://m.henrys.com/

There are plenty of "carousel" jQuery plugins, but how can I bind a carousel next/prev page action to the "swipe" mobile phone/tablet gesture?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either you use a JQM plugin for that (I've seen some available), or you add your own touch event management and manually call the next/prev on your chosen plugin.

For example,

```
$(document).swiperight(function(){
  jqPlugin.goPrev();
});

$(document).swipeleft(function(){
  jqPlugin.goNext();
});
```

More details on JQM events can be found in their [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)

Comment: but... can you quote some of the good jqm carousel plugins you saw, please? :)

Comment: here's one I just found - [JQM carousel widget](https://github.com/andrebrov/jqm.carousel), demo looks good but I personally have never used it...

Comment: maybe in the demo, but in the jscript world it's all dynamic ;-)

Comment: The one from WooThemes is nice, and supports touch: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/basic-carousel.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is code of their jQuery carousel plugin

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.slideCarousel = function (options) {
        var options = jQuery.extend({
            duration: 500,
            current_slide: 0,
            counter_slide: false,
            structure_counter_parent: "<div class='slider-counter'></div>",
            structure_counter_el: "<span></span>",
            counter_slide_number: false,
            btn_next: false,
            btn_prev: false,
            slide_switch: false,
            slide_timer: 10000
        }, options);

        return this.each(function () {

            var elem = this;
            var slides = $(elem).children();
            var slide_last = slides.length - 1;
            var img_list = $(elem).find('img');
            var current_slide = options.current_slide;
            var current_slide_counter = options.current_slide;
            var width_elem;
            var nav_version = navigator.appVersion;
            var permit_next = true;
            var css_transitions;
            var css_transform;
            var _timer;
            var transit_timer;
            var agent = null;
            var orient_change = true;
            var link_counter;

            $(elem).closest("*[data-role='page']").bind('pageshow', setup);

            $(window).bind('resize orientationchange', function () {
                if (!permit_next) {
                    orient_change = false;
                    return;
                }
                size_change();
            });

            function size_change() {
                size_slider();
                fix_slider();
                return false;
            }

            if (css_supports('transition')) {
                css_transitions = true;
                if (agent === null) {
                    agent = GetAgent();
                }
                var agent_low = agent.replace(/^[a-zA-Z]/, function (value) {
                    return value.toLowerCase();
                });
                slides.bind(agent_low + 'TransitionEnd transitionend', TransitionEnd);
            }

            if (css_supports('transform')) {
                if (agent === null) {
                    agent = GetAgent();
                }
                if (agent == 'Webkit') {
                    if (nav_version.indexOf('BlackBerry') == -1 || nav_version.indexOf('Version/7') == -1) {
                        if (nav_version.indexOf('Android') == -1 || $(elem).closest("*[data-role='page']").find('select').length == 0) {
                            css_transform = true;
                            slides.css(agent + 'Transform', 'translate3d(0px,0px,0px)');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (nav_version.indexOf('Android 2.1') != -1) {
                if (document.getElementsByTagName('iframe').length > 0) {
                    $(elem).closest("*[data-role='page']").bind('pagebeforehide', function () {
                        $(this).nextAll("[data-role='page']").bind('pagebeforeshow', function () {
                            window.location.reload();
                        });
                    });
                }
            }

            function css_supports(css_prop) {
                var div = document.createElement('div'),
                    vendors = 'Khtml Ms O Moz Webkit'.split(' '),
                    len = vendors.length;
                if (css_prop in div.style) return true;
                css_prop = css_prop.replace(/^[a-z]/, function (val) {
                    return val.toUpperCase();
                });
                while (len--) {
                    if (vendors[len] + css_prop in div.style) {
                        agent = vendors[len];
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

            function GetAgent() {
                $.browser.chrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

                if ($.browser.chrome) return "Moz";
                if ($.browser.mozilla) return "Moz";
                if ($.browser.opera) return "O";
                if ($.browser.safari) return "Webkit";
                if ($.browser.msie) return "Ms";
            }

            function setup() {
                if (agent == 'Webkit') {
                    if (img_list.length > 0) img();
                }
                loadEnd();
            }

            function img() {
                var call_back = 0;
                var error_back = 0;
                img_list.each(function () {
                    $(this).bind('error', function () {
                        error_back++;
                        img_event(call_back + error_back);
                    });
                    $(this).bind('load', function () {
                        call_back++;
                        img_event(call_back + error_back);
                    });
                });
            }

            function img_event(event_back) {
                if (event_back == img_list.length) {
                    loadEnd();
                }
            }

            function loadEnd() {
                addClass();
                size_slider();
                fix_slider();
            };

            function addClass() {
                var i = 0;
                slides.each(function () {
                    $(this).addClass('slide-item-' + i);
                    i++;
                })
            }

            function size_slider() {
                var height = 0;
                offTransition();
                width_elem = $(elem).width();
                slides.css('width', width_elem);
                slides.each(function () {               
                    if ($(this).outerHeight() > height) height = $(this).outerHeight();
                });             
                $(elem).css('height', height);
            }

            function fix_slider() {
                offTransition();
                if (css_transform) {
                    slides.not('.slide-item-' + current_slide).css(agent + 'Transform', 'translate3d' + '(' + width_elem + 'px,0,0)');
                    slides.filter('.slide-item-' + current_slide).css(agent + 'Transform', 'translate3d(0,0,0)');
                    return;
                }
                slides.not('.slide-item-' + current_slide).css('left', width_elem);
                slides.filter('.slide-item-' + current_slide).css('left', 0);
            }

            if (options.counter_slide) {
                $(elem).after(options.structure_counter_parent);
                link_counter = $(elem).next();
                slides.each(function () {
                    link_counter.append(options.structure_counter_el);
                });
                if (options.counter_slide_number) {
                    var i = 1;
                    link_counter.find("*:empty").each(function () {
                        $(this).text(i);
                        i++;
                    })
                }
            }

            addCheck();

            function slideCounter() {
                link_counter.children().removeClass('current');
                link_counter.children().eq(current_slide).addClass('current');
            }

            function addCheck() {
                if (options.counter_slide) slideCounter();
                if (options.slide_switch) onTimer();
            }

            function onTimer() {
                _timer = setTimeout(function () {
                    slideNext();
                }, options.slide_timer)
            }

            function offTransition() {
                if (css_transitions) {
                    slides.css('transition-property', 'none')
                    .css(agent + 'TransitionProperty', 'none');
                }
            }

            function TransitionEnd() {
                if (!orient_change) {
                    size_change();
                    orient_change = true;
                }
                permit_next = true;
            }

            $(elem).bind('swipeleft', slideNext);
            if (options.btn_next) {
                $(options.btn_next).bind('tap', slideNext);
            };

            $(elem).bind('swiperight', slidePrev);
            if (options.btn_prev) {
                $(options.btn_prev).bind('tap', slidePrev);
            };

            function checkDevice() {
                if (true) {
                    $(document).scrollTop($(document).scrollTop() + 1);
                }
            }

            function preparation_next() {
                var current_slide_;
                offTransition();
                if (current_slide > slide_last) current_slide_ = 0;
                else current_slide_ = current_slide;
                if (css_transform) {
                    slides.filter('.slide-item-' + current_slide_).css(agent + 'Transform', 'translate3d' + '(' + width_elem + 'px,0,0)');
                    return;
                }
                slides.filter('.slide-item-' + current_slide_).css('left', width_elem);
            }

            function preparation_prev() {
                var current_slide_;
                offTransition();
                if (current_slide < 0) current_slide_ = slide_last;
                else current_slide_ = current_slide;
                if (css_transform) {
                    slides.filter('.slide-item-' + current_slide_).css(agent + 'Transform', 'translate3d' + '(' + (-width_elem) + 'px,0,0)');
                    return;
                }
                slides.filter('.slide-item-' + current_slide_).css('left', -width_elem);
            }

            function slideNext(event) {
                if (event) event.stopPropagation();
                if (!permit_next) return;
                if (options.slide_switch) clearTimeout(_timer);
                current_slide++;
                preparation_next();
                slideToggle('next');
            }

            function slidePrev(event) {
                if (event) event.stopPropagation();
                if (!permit_next) return;
                if (options.slide_switch) clearTimeout(_timer);
                current_slide--;
                preparation_prev();
                slideToggle('prev');
            }

            function slideToggle(direct) {
                if (css_transitions) {
                    if (transit_timer) return;
                    transit_timer = setTimeout(function () {
                        slides.css('transition', 'all ' + options.duration + 'ms')
                        .css(agent + 'Transition', 'all ' + options.duration + 'ms');
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            if (direct == 'next') {
                                if (css_transform) {
                                    slides.filter('.slide-item-' + (current_slide - 1)).css(agent + 'Transform', 'translate3d' + '(' + (-width_elem) + 'px,0,0)');
                                    if (current_slide > slide_last) current_slide = 0;
                                    slides.filter('.slide-item-' + current_slide).css(agent + 'Transform', 'translate3d(0,0,0)');
                                }
                                else {
                                    slides.filter('.slide-item-' + (current_slide - 1)).css('left', -width_elem);
                                    if (current_slide > slide_last) current_slide = 0;
                                    slides.filter('.slide-item-' + current_slide).css('left', 0);
                                }
                            }
                            else if (direct == 'prev') {
                                if (css_transform) {
                                    slides.filter('.slide-item-' + (current_slide + 1)).css(agent + 'Transform', 'translate3d' + '(' + width_elem + 'px,0,0)');
                                    if (current_slide < 0) current_slide = slide_last;
                                    slides.filter('.slide-item-' + current_slide).css(agent + 'Transform', 'translate3d(0,0,0)');
                                }
                                else {
                                    slides.filter('.slide-item-' + (current_slide + 1)).css('left', width_elem);
                                    if (current_slide < 0) current_slide = slide_last;
                                    slides.filter('.slide-item-' + current_slide).css('left', 0);
                                }
                            }
                            addCheck();
                            transit_timer = false;
                        }, 1);
                    }, 20);
                }
                else {
                    if (direct == 'next') {
                        slides.filter('.slide-item-' + (current_slide - 1)).animate({ left: -width_elem }, options.duration);
                        if (current_slide > slide_last) current_slide = 0;
                        slides.filter('.slide-item-' + current_slide).animate({ left: 0 }, options.duration, TransitionEnd);
                    }
                    else if (direct == 'prev') {
                        slides.filter('.slide-item-' + (current_slide + 1)).animate({ left: width_elem }, options.duration);
                        if (current_slide < 0) current_slide = slide_last;
                        slides.filter('.slide-item-' + current_slide).animate({ left: 0 }, options.duration, TransitionEnd);
                    }
                    addCheck();
                }
                if (options.duration > 1) permit_next = false;
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```